# Description field size limitation

Tags: manual-testing

in my application, there is a Description field that the user once he creates a package, can enter some type of description story.

Currently that filed is not limited to a specific number of characters, which for some reason i am not too comfortable with, as i feel wrong entries of thousands of characters might blow up the DB.

My question = Should i consider it a defect and recommend to limit it to lets say 500 characters ?   Or Leave it ?

Comment: What requirements say? What onsite customer says? Where you got value of 500 from?

Comment: @Peter Masiar, 
Requirements = Null.          
Onsite Customer = this will be new, so feedback yet.
500 from a previous project, in a different company.

Comment: " Requirements = Null " - does it mean you have no requirement? Words are better than algebra :-)

Comment: @PeterMasiar,  

NULL referring to that Requirements did not specify anything for this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach will be like this.
First check the requirement doc, what it says about the description field length. If there is nothing about the description field then try as followed:

Try input long description say thousands of char. submit it and then verify it on the backend.
In case the whole description is not getting stored then it's an ISSUE.
or you can put it as SUGGESTION/ENHANCEMENT if the long description is getting saved.

Comment: Good deal.

That was one of my choices to try.  
Load 100K character (or as much i can) let either save or Blow up.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have requirements, write one and get them to your customer to comment. Suggest deadline for review, and any comments after deadline might be treated differently (extra price, whatever). You are creating the paper trail of attempts to solve problems.

But all this is not your problem as QA. It is problem which your manager needs to solve (whoever told you to test this). Communication is better than documentation, or better: documentation is not a replacement of communication.

Comment: Good deal.

Your input is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> Currently that filed is not limited to a specific number of
>   characters, which for some reason i am not too comfortable with, as i
>   feel wrong entries of thousands of characters might blow up the DB.
>
> My question = Should i consider it a defect and recommend to limit it
>   to lets say 500 characters ? Or Leave it ?

If there are requirements, they should tell you the required field size.

If not, check the database - how large a field is being used to store this value?

Then, what happens when you exceed that size in the UI? Does it actually "blow up the DB"? If so write a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but I like where Joe and Amol are. If there are no requirements, break it. Put a million characters in there. Write a script to fill in 100 description fields with 14000 characters each. Try all the things.

And talk to the team. Maybe this won't break it, but it may fill it up which could be undesirable for other reasons.